# button attribute "disable" not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my fiddle here:http://jsfiddle.net/qJdaA/2/
this code is suppose to disable the `#monitor` button when there is none checked checkbox.

```
        var checked = $('#status_table tr [id^="monitor_"]:checked');
        if (checked.index()==-1){
            $('#monitor').attr('disabled','true');

        }
```

But it does not seem to be working. What's wrong?

EDIT: i found out i'm getting blurred with my code. to simplify the whole thing, may be i should change the logic :s How should i do it if i want to enable the monitor button ONLY if there is at least a checkbox been checked?

Answer (score 3):

Try using this condition:

```
if (checked.length === 0) {
```

And you should use `.prop()`, not `.attr()` for setting the disabled state (as well as things like `checked` and `selected`).

So it would be:

```
$("#monitor").prop("disabled", true); // (or false, to enable it)
```

References:

- `.prop()` vs. `.attr()`: [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)
- `.prop()`: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: Thank you for the answer. i realized that there is much other problems with the code now (please refer my edited question). Thank you again :)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#monitor').prop('disabled',true);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/CyfGT/)

Comment: but it seems the same :( i think there may be other problems. please see my edited question above. thank you! :)